# How to validate XML file using an XSD locally?

Tags: xml, xsd

How can I validate XML file using an XSD locally on my PC?

Answer (score 4):

I have written a number of xsd to validate an xml -- most solution came from this site.  I've focused more on using [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)!

`xmllint -schema <your xsd file>  <your xml file>`

HTH

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to put the xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation attribute into your root tag pointing to your local xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2020.2"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="your-schema.xsd">
   <....>
....
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an occasional requirement to validate individual files in an ad-hoc way, consider getting an IDE such as oXygen or Stylus Studio - unless you're comfortable using tools from the command line.

If it's a regular process that you want to automate, then I think we need to know more about the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

For validating XML files against a XSD you have several options. Here are two of these which I find useful.

One option is to use [Apache Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/) Parser. Xerces is available for Java as well as for C++.

Another option I often use is the XML plug-in in Notepad++. You can validate your xml against a chosen XSD very easy. [Here](http://when-others-then-null.blogspot.de/2012/12/Validate-XML-against-an-XSD-using-npp.html) is a very well description.